# Windows 10 never boots again after connecting to internet

Tags: windows-10, boot, lenovo-laptop

I have a fresh Windows 10 install (not an upgrade) on my Lenovo L540.
It is perfectly running until I connect to internet. Once I do that, after I restart the computer (the restart it taking several long minutes), it never boots up again.
I can just see a Windows logo and loading circle for ever. 
I tried to disable automatic updates, also upgraded graphic drivers...
No success. Is there some log I can watch?

Thanks

edit: HyperV is disabled.

Comment: I don't think that connecting to the Internet caused the issue. It sounds more like a corrupt install of Windows.  I would try a clean install of Windows.

Comment: I did a clean install of Windows 8x times today! I'm writing it is the clean install..

Comment: The initial updates for Windows 10 (from your 'fresh' install to the 'current' version) are potentially large, and depending on the hardware, it could run _hours_. I would give it a night and see if that helps.

Comment: Didn't help during the whole night. Seems to be a problem with cumulative update KB3140743, but I don't know how to uninstall that, because I'm not able to boot it even into safe mode..

Answer (score 0):

So was a graphic card driver. So I made a fresh install, blocked all Windows updates by setting them to notify restart and deffer the upgrades, whant I used wushow.diagcab to block the wrong one.